# Can XML::LibXML add nodes to a document based on XPath alone?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm looking for a method that allows me to spring to life a text node that something like:

```
$doc->addNode( $xPath );
```

The fact that XPath queries can get quite funky at times is probably a good enough reason for not implementing such a method inside [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML).

But the simpler, absolute XPaths do provide a convenient address representation for nodes. There are times when such a method makes life a whole lot easier, as well as a whole lot more sense.

To address this need, I rolled my own overly-simplistic sub that performs a recursive walk up the XPath until an existing XPath is found, at which point the necessary nodes are created and added. While it works for the time being, it doesn't handle indexed XPaths (like `/library/book[2]/title`) and references to `text()` nodes need to be stripped out.

I'm hoping there is an alternative solution that fulfills my requirement. Writing my own XPath-parser/node-generator is way too much work for what it's worth.

Comment: XPaths aren't really suitable. What should `//foo` create? Should `/foo[@bar=4]` create a new `foo` with the specified attribute if the path doesn't match, or should it set the attribute on an existing `foo` element? What do you do when the XPath matches more than one node? etc etc etc

Comment: In order for us to provide an "alternative solution that fulfills my requirement", it would help if you specified your requirements. Right now, we only have the description of a broken implementation.